# SQRDReaderSDK.shared.authorize() doesn't have callback initially

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, square-connect, square

I currently am unable to authorize the SquareReaserSDK with iOS (Swift).

1. I have a node instance that takes in an **access_token**.
2. I then call **listLocations()**
3. I provide the first **location_id** in the body of a **CreateMobileAuthorizationCodeRequest()**
4. I then pass the resulting mobile auth code to the client

After successfully retrieving a mobile auth token and providing that to the below, the first time this is called there is no callback. The block if statement never fires.

Redundant calls results in an **authorization_already_in_progress** error (the if statement is fired).

```
SQRDReaderSDK.shared.authorize(withCode: mobileAuthToken) { location, error in

        if let authError = error {
             print("Authorize SquareReaderSDK", authError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
             print("Authorize SquareReaderSDK", location)
             Defaults[.establishment]?.squareMobileAuthToken = mobileAuthToken as! String
        }
}
```

**authorize() endpoint reference:** https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/reader/ios/Classes/SQRDReaderSDK.html#/Authorization

**Redundant calls results in:**

```
vvvvv SQUARE ERROR vvvvv

ERROR: Something went wrong. Please contact the developer of this application and provide them with this error code: authorization_already_in_progress
DEBUG CODE: authorization_already_in_progress
DEBUG MESSAGE: Authorization is already in progress. Please wait for SQRDReaderSDK.shared.authorize() to complete.

^^^^^ SQUARE ERROR ^^^^^
```

At any point while trying to authorize the device, I get the following error when trying to present the checkoutController:

```
Checkout Failed:
    This device is not currently authorized to accept payments with Square.
```

Comment: It's a little bit hard to tell what is happening with a limited view of your implementation of the `.authorize()` method. Does your implementation roughly follow along with what is seen in the [QuickStart](https://github.com/square/reader-sdk-ios-quickstart/blob/21b2750c28a3ca74b05167ea9649fd0f849db44c/ReaderSDKSample/Screens/Authorization/AuthorizeViewController.swift)? My gut tells me that its running through one time, but never has the success callback called and you're running into the issue when try to authorize again while the previous instance is still awaiting the callback to fire.

Comment: Hey @mootrichard really appreciate your thoughts. Correct, following docs verbatim and there must be some disconnect with `authorize()`... is there a more appropriate place we can chat briefly?

Comment: Sure, you can always hop into the [Square Developer community](https://squ.re/slack) to chat about your implementation.